# How to get all dates in the last X months

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime

I want to get all dates in the last three months, so I did the following:

```
protected void BindPermissions(int empNum)
        {
            var permPeriod = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            permPeriod.Add(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
            permPeriod.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Year, (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month));
            permPeriod.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).Year, (DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).Month));
            var dt = payload_object.AttendancePermissionBO.permissionList
                .Where(x => x.empNum == empNum
                && ((x.permDate.Year == permPeriod.Keys.ElementAtOrDefault(0) && x.permDate.Month == permPeriod.Values.ElementAtOrDefault(0)) ||
                (x.permDate.Year == permPeriod.Keys.ElementAtOrDefault(1) && x.permDate.Month == permPeriod.Values.ElementAtOrDefault(1)) ||
                (x.permDate.Year == permPeriod.Keys.ElementAtOrDefault(2) && x.permDate.Month == permPeriod.Values.ElementAtOrDefault(2)))).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.permDate);
            GV_PermissionHistory.DataSource = dt;
            GV_PermissionHistory.DataBind();
        }
```

---

Is there a better way to do that or this method suits what i need?

Comment: @YongShun: Could You explain please

Comment: Is this is what you need? [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZQpMoU)

Comment: `var threeMonthAgoDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);` and `.Where(x => x.permDate >= threeMonthAgoDate.Date)`? Which the date is greater than (inclusive) the date with 3 months ago will be fulfilled.

Comment: @YongShun Great this's what I want but the last three months including the current

Comment: Hi, *but the last three months including the current*, is it not fulfill your requirement? Can you try to further elaborate for a better understanding? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun I mean when I edit it `var threeMonthAgoDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2);` instead of `-2` it works well because I want the last three months including the current `ex: 7,6,5`

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare Just out of curiosity: Does your current implementation work for you?

Comment: So your requirement should be starting date from 05/05/2022 to 05/07/2022?

Comment: @YongShun No, the whole month, I ignore days in my calc, I want the last three months from day 1 the last month, then we have to do some edit here right?

Comment: I see, based on what your requirement and original code, Astrid's answer is what you need.

Comment: I initially found it hard to tell what the goal actually was. When reading the text in isolation, I understood it how you understood it, Yong Shun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you do not really want *all dates in the last three months*, but you want all items in your collection where `permDate` is a date within some date range.

Given your own approach, that *some date range* seems to be the two previous months plus the entire current month. I.e. for 5th of July 2022, the date range is all of May, June and July 2022.

I think you can simplify your approach by defining a *start date* and an *end date*, and compare the `permDate` values with those two values. A straight-forward way of doing that could be:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var startMonth = today.AddMonths(-2);
var endMonth = today.AddMonths(1);

var startDate = new DateTime(startMonth.Year, startMonth.Month, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(endMonth.Year, endMonth.Month, 1);
```

Then, you can use `startDate` and `endDate` in your filtering:

```
var dt = payload_object.AttendancePermissionBO.permissionList
    .Where(x => 
        x.empNum == empNum &&
        x.permDate >= startDate &&
        x.permDate < endDate)
    .OrderBy(x => x.permDate)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the date (boundary) three months ago from today.

```
DateTime threeMonthsAgoDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
```

2. Filter the data for `permDate` that after (inclusive) the date from 3 months ago.

```cs
var dt = payload_object.AttendancePermissionBO.permissionList
    .Where(x => x.empNum == empNum
        && x.permDate >= threeMonthsAgoDate.Date)
    .OrderBy(x => x.permDate)
    .ToList();
```

**Updated:**

This answer is for querying records from the last 3 months ago until the current date.

Based on Post Owner's requirements and existing code, what he needs is from

> Start Date: 2022-05-01

> End Date: 2022-07-31 (inclusive)

Hence @Astrid's answer is most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for all the dates of last X- months. You can do some changes based on your requirements.

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        var list= new List<DateTime>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            var month= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i);
            var monthDates= GetDates(month.Year, month.Month);
            
            list.AddRange(monthDates);
        }
        
        foreach(var item in list){
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
    
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))  
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)) 
                    .ToList(); 
}
```